# Googletrans return Hindi translation in English Script

Tags: python, google-translation-api

When trying to use the googletrans service for translating English text to Hindi, the output comes out in Hindi script. Is it possible for me to set the script to English?

For example

```
print(googletrans.Translator().translate('Tum kon ho?',src='hindi',dest='english').text)
```

returns output as 'Who are you?'

However, when I do this the other way

```
print(googletrans.Translator().translate('Who are you?',src='english',dest='hindi').text)
```

The output comes out to be 'तुम कौन हो?'

Is there any way to return this output as 'Tum kon ho?'

Comment: "Is there any way to return this output as 'Tum kon ho?'" Why is that the correct answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the object returned from the translate method their should be a property called "pronunciation"

```
print(googletrans.Translator().translate('Who are you?',src='english',dest='hindi').pronunciation)
```